# How to transfer chosen listWidget value on second window into lineEdit on first window when I click pb_2 on second window

Tags: python, pyqt5

pyqt5_two_window_interaction

[image]

I can open second window by clicking pb_1 on first window. Now, I want to transfer chosen listWidget value on second window into lineEdit on first window when I click pb_2 on second window.

[first_win.py]

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys
from PyQt5 import uic
import second_win

form_class = uic.loadUiType("first_window.ui")[0]

class Window(QMainWindow, form_class):
    def __init__(self, parent =None):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('first window')

        self.pb_1.clicked.connect(self.call_2nd_window)

        self.show()

    def call_2nd_window(self):
        self.sw = second_win.Window()
        self.sw.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[second_win.py]

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys
from PyQt5 import uic

form_class = uic.loadUiType("second_window.ui")[0]

class Window(QMainWindow, form_class):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('second window')

        my_list = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
        self.listWidget.addItem(my_list[0])
        self.listWidget.addItem(my_list[1])
        self.listWidget.addItem(my_list[2])

        self.pb_2.clicked.connect(self.send_data)

        self.show()

    def send_data(self):
        currentItem = self.listWidget.currentItem()
        # ???????
        # ???????
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.button = QPushButton("Click",self)

        #special line class
        self.line = drop_line(self)

        self.button.move(20,100)
        self.line.move(140,100)

        #list widget open
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.list_open)

        self.resize(320,250)
        self.show()
    
    def list_open(self):
        #special list_widget class
        self.list_widget = list_widget()

    
class drop_line(QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dropEvent(self, e):
        self.setText(e.mimeData().text())


class list_widget(QListWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        #drag_event control true or false
        self.drag_control = 0

        self.item1 = QListWidgetItem()
        self.item2 = QListWidgetItem()
        self.item3 = QListWidgetItem()

        self.item1.setText("item1")
        self.item2.setText("item2")
        self.item3.setText("item3")

        self.addItem(self.item1)
        self.addItem(self.item2)
        self.addItem(self.item3)

        #for drag starting set control
        self.itemPressed.connect(self.press)

        self.resize(320,250)
        self.show()

    def press(self, e):
        #control = 1 ==> drag starting with moveevent
        self.drag_control = 1
        #e ==> pressed item
        self.drag_text = e.text()
    
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, e):
        #control reset with mouserelease
        self.drag_control = 0
    
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        #drag is started with control == 1
        if self.drag_control == 1:
            self.drag = QDrag(self)
            self.mime = QMimeData()
            self.mime.setText(self.drag_text)
            self.drag.setMimeData(self.mime)
            self.drag.exec_()


app = QApplication([])
window = main()
app.exec()
```